# CNAME record/alias in windows hosts file?

Tags: windows, cname-record, hosts, alias

Is it possible to enter some sort of CNAME record or alias in the windows hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)?

Basically I want to forward all requests made to host A to host B, without having to hard code the IP address (which changes frequently).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The windows hosts file supports only ip->name mappings, it does not support any other standard DNS record types.  See here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx#EDAA

I would recommend running a simple dns server in order to do the redirect you are talking about.  Try powerdns  http://www.powerdns.com/

Answer (score 8):

PowerDNS is not supported on Windows. I would recommend a tool such as "[SimpleDNS](https://simpledns.com/)" (14 day Trial) or 
"[Technitium DNS Server](https://technitium.com/dns/)" (free)  which can be used to create a simple local DNS server.

Once you setup the program, you can create a zone and record for the CNAME you're trying to test and point your DNS server settings  to **127.0.0.1** only to test.

[image: DNS Settings]

I was able to use this to test TrafficManager and this looks to be the easiest way to do it on a Windows computer.

Comment: Anyone found an alternative for Mac?

Comment: @eos I didn't try it out personally, but a googling gives me a number of alternatives. For example this one https://www.mamp.info/namo/en/

Comment: +1 for Technitium - very easy to set up